# Terraform - Lambda function unable to modify - Error: error modifying Lambda Function (lamda name) configuration : ValidationException:

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

I have created a lambda successfully thru terraform script. But now when I run an apply it throws the following error:

```
    Error: error modifying Lambda Function (mylambda) configuration 
    : ValidationException: 
     status code: 400, request id: d6c28f7c-49b4-4edd-848e-a2a763242e09
```

This is the code:

```
  data "archive_file" "lambda_zip_mylambda" {
           type        = "zip"
           source_dir = "./Packages/aaa/index"
           excludes    = [ ".gitkeep" ]
           output_path = "./Packages/aaa/index/index.zip"
  }
  resource "aws_lambda_function" "mylambda" {
          description      = "-"
          function_name    = var.lambdafunctionname
          handler          = "lambda_handler"
          runtime          = "python3.8"
          filename     = data.archive_file.lambda_zip_mylambda.output_path
          source_code_hash =   
                   data.archive_file.lambda_zip_mylambda.output_base64sha256
         role             = var.lambda_role_arn
         tags             = var.lambdatags
         timeout          = 300
         memory_size      = 128
    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you changing? What is `var.lambdafunctionname` now and before?

Comment: Well, so what exactly did you modify? What is the full TF plan output?

Comment: The lambda was created manually. I was able to run the terraform import command and it got imported into the state file successfully. Looks my terraform code which I wrote is not matching with the imported lambda into the state file

Comment: This is resolved. Weird thing is, Terraform doesn't pin point which attribute it doesn't like